# How do I compile assemble file to a 512b file?

Tags: bootloader

I want to write a tiny bootloader, I use command "as boot.s" to compile it. I think I should have got a 512B file, but I get a 1448B file which is too large to be a bootloader.
what's wrong with my code? thx.

```
.code16
.global _start
_start:
    movw $0x7c00, %ax
    movw %ax, %ds
    movw %ax, %es
    call Dispstr
    call loop
Dispstr:
    movw BootMessage, %ax
    movw %ax, %bp
    movw $0x1301, %ax
    movw $0x000c, %bx
    movb $0, dl
    int $0x10
    ret
loop:
    jmp loop
BootMessage:
    .asciz "Hellow World"
.org 510, 0
.word 0xaa55
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
times 510-($-$$) db 0   ; Pad remainder of boot sector with 0s
dw 0xAA55       ; The standard PC boot signature
```

instead of

```
.org 510, 0
.word 0xaa55
```

also, see this article http://mikeos.berlios.de/write-your-own-os.html

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved it myself.
LD --oformat binary -o boot boot.o
cut off ELF file header